# Android tablet ethernet connection for network communication?

Tags: android, android-studio, raspberry-pi, jailbreak, ethernet

It seems like my Samsung tablet rejects and loses its ethernet connection when I connect anything other than internet via micro-usb to ethernet adapter.
I'm trying to connect Raspberry Pi and the tablet via ethernet cable and stream video from the pi to the tablet with network stream in my app or VLC i.e. http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port#

Is there a way for me to do that with Samsung tablet? Samsung tech has told me that their tablets support ethernet connection only for internet. And it loses its connection if there isn't any response to ping, I think.

I'm considering rooting too. If I root, how can I disable the ping or send imaginary response to the ping when I connect ethernet cable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made recently roughly similar setup and got it to work.

I used Samsung Tab S2 (and later Samsung Tab S3) as a tablet and Odroid XU4 as a single-board computer instead of Raspberry Pi since I needed more processing power.

Ethernet connection worked when I used a fixed IP in the tablet and did everything in correct order:

1. First, disable Wifi and mobile data
2. Connect Ethernet and set fixed IP in Settings
3. Open video stream
4. Enable Wifi and/or mobile data
5. Use another browser tab/app to connect to the Internet (the Ethernet connection stayed alive in my tests)
6. If necessary, use a port forwarding app to share the video stream to other devices over Wifi

However, I ended up using USB Tethering instead of Ethernet. It was more simple and more reliable solution. The way I did it is documented here:
https://github.com/FinweLtd/mjpg-streamer/tree/master/scripts#mobile-streaming

Both solutions worked without rooting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A couple more questions for you if you don't mind.  1. Did your setup with wired Ethernet cable pose any latency in streaming? 2. How about USB Tethering setup? Did it have any noticeable latency?